# Table of content doesn't have hyperlinks in PDF exported from Word

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf

I've created a table of content in my Word document, and the page numbers are hyperlinks. However, when I export the document to PDF, it is no longer possible to click on the page numbers in the TOC to jump to the respective page.

How can I preserve the links in the TOC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This has nothing to do with the conversion to pdf. It has to do with the presence of the hyperlinks in the TOC to start with.* For some reason, your TOC is missing the \h switch.

### By default, a TOC is built with hyperlinks to the source in the document.

Here is the code of the standard table of contents field, without any alterations:

```
{ TOC \o "1-3" \h \z \u }
```

That field code produces hyperlinks in the pdf.

It is the code produced by this dialog:

[image: screenshot of dialog]

That dialog comes up if the user selects Custom Table of Contents or uses the Field insertion dialog under Insert > Quick Parts > Field. That default dialog does have the option checked. This option should have no effect on pdf files, which are not web previews, but apparently, it does.

Here are my primary reference on Tables of Contents, both by Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill.

- [TOC Tips and Tricks](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/TOCTips.htm)
- [TOC Switches](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/TOCSwitches.htm)

Note that the browser version of Word does not allow manipulation of this field.

I always use the Custom Table of Contents and seldom change the options. The reason I do this is that both of the "Automatic" Tables of Contents insert the field in an extraneous Content Control which slows down response times and, as far as I can tell, helps with nothing. The Custom Table of Contents inserts the bare field as does using Insert > Quick Parts > Fields > TOC.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, which is better than my own.

Comment: You are welcome. I completely understand how it can happen since the dialog box is misleading.

Comment: My TOC has precisely the same switches as yours, but the resultant PDF does not have a clickable TOC. Hyperlinks in the doc are fine, but the TOC does not behave as a set of hyperlinks when converted to a PDF - notwithstanding the \h switch and notwithstanding that the entries look like hyperlinks in Web Layout mode.  For reference, I am using Word for Mac on an M2 MacBook Pro running Ventura, and have opened the doc in various applications (Preview, Chrome, Adobe, etc).  Just in case I misunderstood your answer, did your TOC result in clickable links?

Comment: The workaround I found was to open the Word document in Pages on a Mac, and then use File | Export to PDF to save it as a PDF.  The resultant PDF had a fully clickable Table of Contents (just as in the original Word document), and I didn't even need to save the original Word document in Pages.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, Word removes the link from the page number during the PDF export. AFAIK, there is no way to prevent this. What is possible though, is to turn the entire TOC entry into a hyperlink. To do this, the TOC option "Links instead of page numbers" needs to be enabled. You can get to this option in the following way:

1. Right-click just to the left of the first letter of the TOC
2. Select "Edit field"
3. Click on the "Table of contents" button for the extended field options
4. Below "Web preview" (!), select the option "Use hyperlinks instead of page numbers"
5. Select "Yes" when propted if you want to replace the table of contents

Now, each TOC line should be a hyperlink. These links are preserved when exporting the document to PDF.

Comment: This should be posted as an edit to your question. Not as an answer.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon: This is an answer (so far the best one) to the question, so it is posted as answer. StackEchange encourages everyone to answer their own question: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: Here is the code of the standard table of contents field, without any alterations `{ TOC \o "1-3" \h \z \u }`. That field code produces hyperlinks in the pdf.

Comment: Which method did you originally use to produce your TOC? The default checks that box. I always recommend simply using the "Custom Table of Contents" which brings up the dialog rather than using one of the gallery items.

Comment: I had unchecked "Use hyperlinks instead of page numbers" in the Table of Contents dialog box because it seemed strange. I wasn't aware on its implications for the PDF export.