# Microsoft Word: How do I create a horizontal TOC with just Heading 1?

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm trying to add this in the footer:

Section 1 | Section 2 | Section 3

It has to be horizontal, and auto update the linking if needed.
I am using a macbook, if that matters.

I have tried asking ChatGPT and even followed the instructions from: [Table of content doesn't have hyperlinks in PDF exported from Word](https://superuser.com/questions/1712197/table-of-content-doesnt-have-hyperlinks-in-pdf-exported-from-word/1713340#1713340)

Comment: You can have a Table of Contents that only reflects Heading 1 and you can place it in the footer. I'm not sure what you mean by horizontal. A TOC in Wordv is a field. http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/TOCTips.htm

Comment: @confake, I'm a bit confused by your question. You ask for a horizontal TOC with just Heading 1 but in your question you like to another question which covers the topic of exporting a document as a PDF and keeping hyperlink capability. Can you elaborate how these two fit together? 
Also, how many Heading 1 paragraphs will you have in your document? If you want to store everything in the footer, this will quickly become a huge footer.

Comment: Hi all, thank you for your quick response. I have 7 chapters. As per client request, they wanted it to be in the footer with it being horizontal: Section 1 | Section 2 | Section 3

I have linked the other question for their TOC code examples. It was my first time knowing Microsoft Word have such a function.

Answer (score 1):

In the footer of all pages by insert on page 1. You can insert hyperlinks as normal line entries, they will contain whatever abbreviation you wish so you could have a short line of

`Section 1 | Section 2 | Section 3 | Section 4 | Section 5 | Section 6 | Section 7`
and they still link to any long section name, they will automatically be repeated unless you alter the section footers.

[image]

In a PDF export they will be **separate from** but hyperlink just the same as bookmarks, thus a good idea to switch both on.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you know that your document will only have 7 headings, then the easiest method is to use cross-references.

1. Go to the "Insert" tab and in the "Links" section, click on "Cross-reference"

[image]

2. In the new window, select the reference type "Heading" and insert a reference to "Heading text". Then select the first heading from the list and click on "Insert".

[image]

3. Repeat the previous step for the remaining headings
4. Insert the "|" characters between your fields